# Checking amount of money in vending machine and prompting if necessary

Tags: java

So I've had little trouble with this project, aside from a few minor issues, and this one continues to stump me. What I need to happen is for this vending machine to test the amount of money the user has entered into the machine to see if it is enough to purchase the item the user wants. If it isn't enough, it needs to prompt the user to add more money or press negative one to exit.

Example:

```
   Please Enter money into the machine (press -1 to exit): <enter such and such amount>
   You now have $1.00. Please select and item (press 0 to exit): <enter selection>

   You do not have enough money. Please add more money or exit the machine.
   Please Enter money into the machine (press -1 to exit): <enter such and such amount>
   You now have $2.00. Please select and item (press 0 to exit): <enter selection>
```

The problem I encounter is I can't get the amount of money AFTER adding more money to print and the website I'm required run the program through for my course throws a NoSuchElementException when it reaches the addMoney scanner. I can't figure out why it would be doing so when there is a double being entered at that point. Any help is much appreciated. I'm sure there's an easier way right?

VendingMachine.java

```
//Runs user inputs and determines the success of transaction
public void vend(double inputMoney,int inputItem) throws NumberFormatException, InputMismatchException {
    NumberFormat d = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean a = false;
    boolean b = false;
    boolean c = false;

    double userMoney = inputMoney;
    int errorNum = 0;
    //double addMoney = 0;
    int itemSelect = inputItem;


    if (userMoney==-4){
        //errorNum=-4;
        //this.outputMessage(userInput, errorNum);
        a = true;
        b=true;
        c=true;
    }
    while(!a){
        b=false;


        while(!b){

            if(itemSelect==0){
                errorNum = -3;
                this.outputMessage(userMoney, errorNum);
                b=true;
                a=true;
            } else if ((userMoney-stock[itemSelect-1].itemPrice)<0.00){
                errorNum=-1;
                this.outputMessage(userMoney, errorNum);
                double newMoney=this.addMoney(userMoney);
                if(newMoney==-1){
                    errorNum=-3;
                    this.outputMessage(userMoney, errorNum);
                    b=true;
                    a=true;
                }
                userMoney = userMoney + newMoney;
                b=true;

            } else if (stock[itemSelect-1].itemQuantity==0){
                errorNum = -2;
                this.outputMessage(userMoney, errorNum);
                b=true;
                a=true;
            } else {
                userMoney = userMoney-stock[itemSelect-1].itemPrice;
                money = (money + stock[itemSelect-1].itemPrice);
                this.outputMessage(userMoney, itemSelect);

                stock[itemSelect-1].itemQuantity = stock[itemSelect-1].itemQuantity - 1;

                b=true;
                a=true;
            }


        }



    }

}

//Prints out appropriate messages based on success of transaction
public void outputMessage(double userInput, int userInput2) {
    NumberFormat d = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    boolean exit = false;
    while(!exit){
        if(userInput2==-1){

            System.out.println("You do not have enough money. Please add more money or exit.");
            System.out.println("Please enter some money into the machine (enter -1 to exit): ");
            exit=true;

        } else if (userInput2==-2) {

            System.out.println("Sorry, we are out of this item.");
            exit=true;

        } else if (userInput2==-3) {

            System.out.println("You did not buy anything from this vending machine. Your change is " + d.format(userInput));
            exit=true;
        } else {

            System.out.println("You have purchased " + stock[userInput2-1].itemDesc + " for " + d.format(stock[userInput2-1].itemPrice) + ". Your change is " + d.format(userInput) + ".");

            exit=true;
        }
    }


}

//To print the items in held in stock
public void printMenu()  {
    NumberFormat price = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    System.out.println("Item#" + "\t" + "Item" + "\t  " + "Price" + "\t  " + "Qty");

    for(int i=0; i<stock.length;i++){
        System.out.println((i+1) + "\t" + stock[i].itemDesc + "\t  " + price.format(stock[i].itemPrice) + "\t  " + stock[i].itemQuantity);
    }

}

public double getMoney() {
    return money;
}

public double addMoney(double userMoney){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    double addMoney = scan.nextDouble();
    double newMoney = userMoney +addMoney;
    return newMoney;
}
```

VendingMachineDriver.java

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String a = new String("a");
    String b = new String("b");
    String x = new String("x");
    int item = 0;
    boolean exit = false;
    VendingMachine drinks = new VendingMachine("src/drinks");
    VendingMachine snacks = new VendingMachine("src/snacks");
    NumberFormat cash = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    while(!exit){
        boolean c = false;
        boolean i = false;
        System.out.println("Welcome to Jeremy's Super Vending Machines!");
        System.out.println("Please select a vending machine:");
        System.out.println("A-Drinks, B-Snacks, X-Exit");
        String vendingSelect = input.next();

        while(!c){
            if(a.equalsIgnoreCase(vendingSelect)){

                drinks.printMenu();
                System.out.println("Please enter some money into the machine (enter -1 to exit)");
                double money = input.nextDouble();

                if (money==-1){
                    int errorNum=-3;
                    drinks.outputMessage(money, errorNum);
                    System.out.println("You did not buy anything from this vending machine. Your change is " + cash.format(0) + "." );
                    c = true;

                } else {
                    while(!i){
                        try{
                            System.out.println("You now have " + cash.format(money) + " to spend. Please make a selection (enter 0 to exit): ");
                            item = input.nextInt();
                            drinks.vend(money, item);
                            i=true;
                        } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid Entry!");
                            input.next();
                        }

                    }
                    //drinks.vend(money, item);


                }
            c=true;


            }

            else if(b.equalsIgnoreCase(vendingSelect)){
                snacks.printMenu();
                System.out.println("Please enter some money into the machine (enter -1 to exit)");
                double money = input.nextDouble();

                if (money==-1){
                    System.out.println("You did not buy anything from this vending machine. Your change is " + cash.format(0) + "." );
                    c = true;

                }
                else {

                    while(!i){
                        try{
                            System.out.println("You now have " + cash.format(money) + " to spend. Please make a selection (enter 0 to exit): ");
                            item = input.nextInt();
                            i=true;
                        } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid Entry!");
                            input.next();
                        }

                    }
                    snacks.vend(money, item);
                    c=true;

                }
            } else if(x.equalsIgnoreCase(vendingSelect)){
                double errorNum = -4;
                snacks.vend(errorNum, item);
                double revenue = drinks.getMoney() + snacks.getMoney();
                System.out.println("The vending machines made a total of " + cash.format(revenue) + "." );
                System.out.println("Thank you for your business!");
                c=true;
                exit=true;
            }

        }


    }
```